# Command History in Rstudio multi-line statements

Tags: r, ide, rstudio

In previous versions of Rstudio when I pressed up in the console pane, I could cycle through the previous R statements, even if they stretched over multiple lines. After updating the behavior changed and pressing up now cycles through all previous lines, which is especially annoying to me when the last lines were long chains of magrittr pipes or additions of ggplot objects.

Is there a setting to get the old behavior back?

My rstudio version:

```
> RStudio.Version()
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2019). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio, Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2019},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.2.1578’
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revert back or download the older version of `R studio` using the below link:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but downgrading is not an option. the new version has more advantages and only this minor disantvantage. Also the question was if I could change the settings, not how to downgrade Rstudio.